# Не отображаются данные в Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, struts

Моя задача : отобразить лист всех пользователей сети. 
   Использую Struts 2.
   Все пользователи добавлены в `ArrayList` следующим образом:

```
ArrayList<User> us = new ArrayList<User>();
```

Далее в JSP файле пытаюсь отобразить всех пользователей, но в итоге ничего не отображается.

```
<s:iterator value="us"><s:property value="username" /></br></s:iterator>
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная `us` не доступна для вью. Чтобы иметь доступ вы должны добавить публичный модификатор к геттеру.

```
public  ArrayList<User> getUs() { return us; }
```

---

JSP используется как шаблон в этом фреймворке. Для того чтобы этот шаблон наполнить данными перед тем как возвращать пользователю нужно использовать тэги. Тэги намного лучше чем скрипты так как они избавляют нас от использования скриптокода в шаблоне, который можно использоавть для дизайна страницы.